# Universal enveloping algebra of an abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

**Corollary**. For each abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, its *universal enveloping algebra* is given by $(\mathfrak{S(g)},i)$, where:

$\cdot\mathfrak{S(g)}$ is the symmetric algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e.
$$\mathfrak{S(g)}:=T(\mathfrak{g})/I, $$ where $I \subset T(\mathfrak{g})$ is the *two-sided ideal generated by the elements* $x \otimes y-y \otimes x$, with $x,y \in \mathfrak{g}$,

$\cdot i:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{S(g)}$ is the injective *linear map* given by $i(x)=x+I.$

I'm try to understand this corollary, but i can't show why the linear map $i:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{S(g)}$ is injective.

It should be simple but I can't prove it. Is the anyone who can help me?

Comment: Well if $i(x) = i(y)$ then $x+I = y+I$ so $y-x \in I$ but $I\cap \mathfrak{g} = {0}$ (viewing both as subsets of $T(\mathfrak{g})$) so $x=y$.

Comment: Sorry, why $I \cap \mathfrak{g}=0$ ?

Comment: $I$ is generated by degree 2 elements so can't contain degree 1 elements (i.e. elements of $\mathfrak{g}$)

Comment: It would probably help to state what this is a corollary of.